# Prove that if $x<0$ then $F_\mu^n(x)\rightarrow -\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $F_\mu=\mu x(1-x)$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Logistic map is given as
$$x_{n+1}=\mu x_n(1-x_n)$$
Let $F_\mu=\mu x(1-x)$.

Therefore, for $\mu>1$, prove that if $x<0$ then $F_\mu^n(x)\rightarrow -\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $\mu>1$. Since $x_0<0$, $\mu\left(1-x_0\right)>t_0$ for some $t_0>1$. Note that $$μ(1−x_n)=\mu(1-x_{n-1})+\mu x_{n-1}^2>μ(1−x_{n−1})>t_0,$$ for every $n$, in particular $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing and  $x_n<t_0^nx_0$ for every $n$. Since $t^nx_0\to-\infty$, this proves that $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $ is strictly decreasing with no
lower bound. (This argument is in @Jean-Claude Arbaut's comment).

Comment: from what we understand that there is no lower bound?

Comment: Excuse me, I have another question. For $0<x<1$ we have that $\mu x(1-x)>x$, thus $x_{n+1}>x_n$: with this reasoning $x_n\rightarrow + \infty$, but is not so.

Comment: $0<x<1$ and $\mu>0$ implies $\mu\left(1-x\right)>0$ and these two
facts imply $\mu x\left(1-x\right)>0$, but not what you claim.

Comment: "Because it's strictly decreasing." Certainly not. The sequence of general term 1/n is strictly decreasing and it has a finite lower bound.

Comment: Thanks @Did. Sometimes one says silly things.

Comment: Now the trouble is that being decreasing and bounded below by -c/2 does not imply that one converges to -c/2. Later on, one uses crucially the hypothesis that c>0, this should be mentioned.

Comment: I meant to say greatest lower bound; I think I fixed both of those things before you commented :)

Comment: Still later on, why $$c+x_{N}\left(\mu+1+\mu\left|x_{N}\right|\right)<\epsilon\implies c+x_{N}<\epsilon/\left(\mu+1+\mu\left|x_{N}\right|\right)\ ?$$ (I find fascinating these answers accepted on the spot, that need serious repairing afterwards.)

Comment: Why not simply write at the beginning that $\mu(1-x)>t>1$, and since $x_n$ is decreasing, all $x_n$ satisfy $\mu(1-x_n)>\mu(1-x_{n-1})>t$, thus $x_n<t^nx_0$.

Comment: Made the (thoroughly revised version of the) answer self-sufficient, as is strongly recommended on this site, with due reference to @Jean-Claude's comment.